# Mule scatter gather doThreading=False means?

Tags: multithreading, mule, scatter

I wanted to copy calling thread's contextMap (MDC) to child thread's context. When I use default threading in scatter gather, I'm not able to copy the values. But when tried custom profile and unchecked "doThreading" (i.e. made it to false), contextMap values are being assigned correctly.

I would like to any performance degradation will happen. I didn't keep any values for maxThreadsActive or TTL etc other than unchecking "doThreading".

```
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
  <threading-profile doThreading="false" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
  <processor-chain>
    bla bla bla....
  </processor-chain>
  <processor-chain>
    bla bla bla...
  </processor-chain>
</scatter-gather>
```

What will be the impact? If two messages comes simultaneously, will they be processed concurrently or second message has to wait till first completes with this configuration in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Naveen To answer your question, I looked for here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/scatter-gather. To make it easier, the answer is here: "The thread executing the flow that owns the router waits until all routes complete or time out."

Also, the part that you used the attribute "doThreading" can be found here https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/tuning-performance

Answer (score 0):

I Just figured out that if do Threading is false, scatter-gather will not process the messages simultaneously. it will dispatch the message to one route and then wait till it's completion before routing message to another route.

By making do threading to false, scatter gather functionality will not be achieved.

I'm still struggling on passing parent's thread context to scatter gather work managers..Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. You can use NDC or MDC here to copy thread context. There are predefined methods to copy ThreadContext and set to other threads.